# Expected a value of type 'A', but got one of type 'B' occurred in bloc Instance of 'Bloc'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I just started learning bloc and I'm trying to make a cart bloc but I'm getting a state error:

*Error: Unhandled error Expected a value of type 'CartSuccess', but got one of type 'CartLoading' occurred in bloc Instance of 'CartBloc'.*

Even if I delete the yield CartLoading(), the error change to:

*Error: Unhandled error Expected a value of type 'CartSuccess', but got one of type 'CartInitial' occurred in bloc Instance of 'CartBloc'.*

**Cart State**

```
abstract class CartState extends Equatable {
  const CartState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CartInitial extends CartState {}

class CartLoading extends CartState {}

class CartSuccess extends CartState {

  final List<ProductModel> carts;

  const CartSuccess(this.carts);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [carts];

}

class CartFailed extends CartState {}
```

**Cart Event**

```
abstract class CartEvent extends Equatable {
  const CartEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class FetchCart extends CartEvent {}

class AddToCart extends CartEvent {
  final ProductModel product;
  const AddToCart(this.product);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}

class RemoveFromCart extends CartEvent {

  final ProductModel product;
  const RemoveFromCart(this.product);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}
```

**Cart Bloc**

```
class CartBloc extends Bloc<CartEvent, CartState> {
  CartBloc() : super(CartInitial());

  @override
  Stream<CartState> mapEventToState(CartEvent event) async* {
    
    yield CartLoading();

    if(event is FetchCart){
      final List<ProductModel> carts = List.from((state as CartSuccess).carts);
      yield CartSuccess(carts);
    }

    if(event is AddToCart){
      try{
        final List<ProductModel> carts = List.from((state as CartSuccess).carts)
          ..add(event.product);
        yield CartSuccess(carts);
      }catch(e){
        yield CartFailed();
        print(e);
      }
    }

    if(event is RemoveFromCart){
      try{
        final carts = (state as CartSuccess)
            .carts
            .where((product) => product.id != event.product.id)
            .toList();
        yield CartSuccess(carts);
      }catch(e){
        yield CartFailed();
        print(e);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this comes from here: `List.from((state as CartSuccess).carts)`. You yield `yield CartLoading();`before this, so your state is no longer CartSuccess but CartLoading. You previous CartSuccess state was lost with yielding CartLoading

Comment: even if i remove the yield CartLoading();, i still get another error Error: Unhandled error Expected a value of type 'CartSuccess', but got one of type 'CartInitial' occurred in bloc Instance of 'CartBloc'

Comment: Sure, because you never come to the point where CartSuccess was the direct predecessor state. Store the state data in a variable within the bloc instead